# nodejs block until 'for' iteration done

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have code like this, and 'for' not executed.

```
var obj = [];
            for (var i = 0, len = param.destinations.length; i < len; i++) {
                var params = {
                    origins: param.origins,
                    destinations: param.destinations[i]
                }
                test(params, function(err, response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    return obj.push(response);
                })
            }
            console.log(obj);
            return callback(null, obj);
```

how to solve that

Comment: if `param.destinations.length` == 0, you'll never do the for

Comment: Does param.destinations has lenght?

Comment: what was an error ?

Comment: What does test do? Is it some async process?

Comment: test is result of value.

Comment: test is some proses

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you run both:

```
console.log(obj);
return callback(null, obj);
```

before any test callback is fired. It will always be `[]` no matter if the loop runs or not.

An easy solution would be something like this:

```
var obj = [];
var n = 0;
for (var i = 0, len = param.destinations.length; i < len; i++) {
    var params = {
        origins: param.origins,
        destinations: param.destinations[i]
    }
    test(params, function(err, response) {
        console.log(response);
        obj.push(response);
        if (++n === len) {
            console.log(obj);
            callback(null, obj);
        }
    })
}
```

You need to have a counter to see how many callbacks have already been called and in the last one do what you need.

This is a manual solution that's good for simple cases like this. For more complex cases you may want to use [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) or do it with [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), maybe using libraries like [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) or [Q](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/).

Comment: @AanElzam call the callback only when the loop counter reaches the last index of the counter

Comment: @AanElzam Or you can use Promise which is designed for this

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that the test() function looks an awful lot like an async function, maybe hitting a database or some other I/O. If that is the case then your return statement can be reached before anthing is ever put in your obj. Make sure test() is synchronous and therefore blocking. Alternative way to look at this is the async function cannot be part of a loop, which is synchronous. Zalgo calls!

So if making it async is not an option the simplest way is to create a variable that counts the number of test() callbacks responded to. Then if the number of callbacks is equal to the number of callbacks you sent then do the final callback.

```
var obj = [];
var testsCompleted = 0;
var len = param.destinations.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var params = {
                    origins: param.origins,
                    destinations: param.destinations[i]
                }
                test(params, function(err, response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    obj.push(response);
                    testsCompleted++;
                    if (testsCompleted == len){
                        console.log(obj);
                        return callback(null, obj);
                }
      })
 }
```